# getting resource limit issue while querying view in athena

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

We have a view in athena which is partitioned on processing_date (data type: string - format 20201231)
We are looking for data in 2020.

For exploration, we need all the columns.

**Query :**

```
select * from online_events_dw_view
where from_iso8601_date(processing_date) > from_iso8601_date('20191231')
```

**Error :**

```
Query exhausted resources at this scale factor
```

Is there any better way to optimize the query

Comment: Can you update your question with the SQL used for view? This error mostly occurs when you have expensive operators operating on large amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

You are applying a function to the partition column, chances are high that this leads to athena scanning all data and therefore you run into the problem.

Why not simply: `processing_date like '2020%'`

Maybe also try with a `limit 1000` to limit the amount of data if you are just interested in the column.

Answer (score 0):

The error "Query exhausted resources at this scale factor" is most often caused when sorting result sets with a lot of columns.

Since you don't post the view SQL there is no way to say for sure if that is the problem in your case, but it's almost always wide rows and sorting so I assume there is an `ORDER BY` in your view. Try removing that and see if the query executes without error.

> Is there any better way to optimize the query

You need to post much more information for us to be able to help you. Without the SQL for the view it is impossible to say anything. Also post the SQL for all involved tables, and give some context about partitioning, the amount of data, the file formats, etc.